# Spanish equivalent of "making jokes/having fun at someone's expense"?

Tags: traducción

I'm trying to translate "making jokes at someone's expense" as opposed to say "making fun of someone" (burlarse de alguien). Do "reírse a costa de alguien", "divertirse a costa de alguien", or "hacer bromas a costa de alguien" sound like proper Spanish?

Comment: making jokes and having fun at someone's expense are not idioms like making fun of someone. It is just writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la Argentina las construcciones más utilizadas son:

- **Hacerle una joda a alguien**: ‘Estamos haciendo una joda a x’
- **Joder a alguien (con algo)**: ‘Estamos jodiendo a x (con la canción que más odia)’
- **Gastar a alguien (con algo)**: ‘Estamos gastando a x (con la canción que más odia)’
- **Cargar a alguien (con algo)**: ‘Estamos cargando a x (con la canción que más odia)’
- **Estar/ser re carnaza (con algo)**: Se usa para *enfatizar la repetición*. En este caso puede decirse que ‘(**él/ella**) Está re carnaza (con esto)’, o bien ‘(**vos**) Estás re carnaza (con esto)’ pero nunca se dice ‘<del>(**yo**) Estoy re carnaza</del>’ porque el término es despectivo. El mismo no es fácil de usar, suele aplicarse cuando alguien es muy insistente con algo y queremos dejarlo de escuchar, pero también aplica a cuando alguien está haciendo una joda repetidas veces y queremos que deje de hacerlo.

Acá en la Argentina la palabra ‘broma’ está pasada de moda, y fue reemplazada por otras como ‘joda’, ‘joder’, ‘gastar’, ‘cargar’, etc. En este mismo sentido, ninguna de tus tres traducciones suena muy natural. Cuál palabra usar dependerá del lugar al que vayas y cuáles sean tus preferencias.

Answer (score 7):

The three options are correct, but "reírse a costa de alguien" sounds more natural to me.

In particular regions, there are colloquial expressions with similar meanings, like "dar chucho" or "dar cuero" in Cuba.

Answer (score 3):

In Spain we would just say *reírse de alguien*, rather than *reírse a costa de alguien*. The latter would be perfectly understood and can be used, but it would sound a bit less natural.